# How to return filtered event log entries for TaskDisplayName = 'Boot Performance Monitoring' using Get-WinEvent in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

The following code works to return the Windows Log events with ID = 100.

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ LogName = "Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational"; StartTime = $Date; ID = 100 } -MaxEvents 1 | Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, Id, Task, TaskDisplayName, LevelDisplayName, Message
```

This code returns an error for the TaskDisplayName = 'Boot Performance Monitoring'

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ LogName = "Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational"; StartTime = $Date; TaskDisplayName = 'Boot Performance Monitoring' } | Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, Id, Task, TaskDisplayName, LevelDisplayName, Message
```

> Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
>   At D:\tfsws\TG-Dev-ICSG2\Support\PowerShell Scripts\Get-WinEvent-TEST.ps1:6 char:1
>   + Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ LogName = "Microsoft-Windows-Diagnos ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

How do I make Get-WinEvent accept the TaskDisplayName filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `-FilterHashTable` to filter on TaskDisplayName for 2 reasons:

In the Microsoft docs [Get-WinEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics/Get-WinEvent?view=powershell-6#required-parameters) valid FilterHashTable values are:

- `LogName=<String[]>`
- `ProviderName=<String[]>`
- `Path=<String[]>`
- `Keywords=<Long[]>`
- `ID=<Int32[]>`
- `Level=<Int32[]>`
- `StartTime=<DateTime>`
- `EndTime=<DataTime>`
- `UserID=<SID>`
- `Data=<String[]>`

TaskDisplayName isn't one of the `-FilterHashTable` options.... ok. So next option is to use `-FilterXPath` or `-FilterXML` which gives us access to some more lower level filtering. For simplicity, I will use `-FilterXPath`. In order to find the right keys to filter on, you have to go to the details tab on the event. Here is a sample event:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance" Guid="{CFC18EC0-96B1-4EBA-961B-622CAEE05B0A}" /> 
    <EventID>100</EventID> 
    <Version>2</Version> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>4002</Task> 
    <Opcode>34</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x8000000000010000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-05-23T21:09:42.047563100Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>8</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation ActivityID="{F774E0CC-F2D9-0006-E0FA-74F7D9F2D301}" /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="3876" ThreadID="4980" /> 
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational</Channel> 
    <Computer>D4700.adcfcu.connectfirstcu.com</Computer> 
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" /> 
</System>
<EventData>
    <Data Name="BootTsVersion">2</Data> 
    <Data Name="BootStartTime">2018-05-23T21:06:49.733345200Z</Data> 
    ..........
    <Data Name="UserLogonWaitDuration">9415</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

When you expand it out, you notice that there is no **`TaskDisplayName`**. This is because `TaskDisplayName == Task Category`. Ok... let's look for `Task Category`... Well there is no `Task Category` either. That's because Categories are actually stored numerically in the event, and then mapped into a proper description using an [Event Category String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231450.aspx). That is why you can't filter based on a `TaskDisplayName` or `Task Category`. Instead you will have to filter on the `Task` number, which you in this case is **`4002`**. And if you use the `StartDate`, which is `TimeCreated`, you can calculate that 30 days is 2592000000 miliseconds, then your code becomes:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational" -FilterXPath "*[System[Task=4002 and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 2592000000]]]" | Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, Id, Task, TaskDisplayName, LevelDisplayName, Message
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-6), the `-FilterHashTable` only allows a subset of filters:

- LogName=
- ProviderName=
- Path=
- Keywords=
- ID=
- Level=
- StartTime=
- EndTime=
- UserID=
- Data=
- *=

What you can do instead, is to create a FilterXML with the `-FilterXML` parameter.
You can create an appropriate XML with `eventvwr.msc` (find and example event, get the task number from the details view, configure a protocol filter, switch to the "XML" tab, and copy the content).

The result will be something like this:

```
$Filter = @'
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational">*[System[(EventID=100) and (Task=4002)]]</Select>
</Query>
</QueryList>
'@
Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $Filter
```

TaskDisplayName however is not a valid property, you have to figure out, what `Task` number 'Boot Performance Monitoring' has. 
Note, that Task `4002` is not the one you are looking for. It's just the only number that is available in my eventlog. ;)

Alterantively, but not as performant and not recommended (general rule: filter left), you can use your sample command and add an `Where-Object` filter.

```
$FitlerHashTable =  @{ 
    LogName = "Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational"
    StartTime = $Date
    ID = 100
}
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable $FitlerHashTable -MaxEvents 1 | 
Where-Object { $_.Task -eq 4002 } | 
Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, Id, Task, TaskDisplayName, LevelDisplayName, Message
```